# I wonder why &a(Data type: char) is printed as value not address, using %s

Tags: c, printf, character, c-strings, conversion-specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char var = 'z';

    printf("[buf]: %s \n", &var); // the output is z~~~~~, but the first char of output is only z. why??
}
```

Comment: `%s` is for strings, so how would that print an address anyway? Also, this is undefined behavior. There's no NUL terminator after `z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion specifier `s` is designed to output strings (or their parts): sequences of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`.

To output the address of an object there is the conversion specifier `p`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    
    printf( "%s\n", s );
    printf( "%p\n", ( void * )s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Hello
0x7ffc86fe4372
```

As for the code in your question then it has undefined behavior because the expression `&var` does not point to a string because the variable `var` is defined like

```
char var = 'z';
```

If you want to output its address then you can do it as

```
printf("[buf]: %p \n", ( void * )&var);
```

Answer (score 0):

`%s` tells `printf` to accept a pointer to the first character of a string and to print that string, up to the null character that indicates its end. Since you pass the address of a single character, `printf` prints that and continues looking in memory for more characters to print, until it finds a byte containing zero. For `%s`, when you pass a pointer to a single character, rather than an array of characters terminated by a null character, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

To print an address, use `%p` and convert the pointer to `void *`:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) &var);
```